# Sql join to skip matched value

Tags: php, sql

I want to join two table such as course and course assign to student.
in course table data example

course table:

```
id | name
1  | computer fundamental
2  | programming with c
3  | electrical engineering
3  | neural network
```

course_to_student table:

```
course_id | std_id
1         | 1
2         | 2
3         | 1
```

then for std id 1: resuld should be

- 2: programming with c
- 4: neural network

and for std_id 2 resuld should be

- 1: computer fundamental
- 3: electrical engineering
- 4:neural network

How can I do that?

Comment: std id : 1 is associated with course id 1 and 3 but you want 2 and 4 . ie. the course not opted by that student right?

Comment: so you want which courses are not assigned to student @saddam hossain

Comment: sorry dude neural network should be 4.

Comment: yes I want which course not assigned to a student -Amit Guad

Answer (score 0):

```
$std_id =1;

SELECT t1.course_id, t1.course_name
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE t1.course_id = t2.course_id
    AND t2.std_id <> $std_id
```

Comment: course table http://prnt.sc/f41o0o  course_enroll_std_ table   http://prnt.sc/f41oqd thank you for checking my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just looking for a `LEFT JOIN` between the two tables.  If I read your expected output correctly, you want to identify courses in which a given student is *not* currently enrolled.

```
SELECT c.name
FROM course c
LEFT JOIN course_to_student s
    ON c.id = s.course_id
WHERE s.course_id IS NULL AND
      s.std_id = 1         -- or s.std_id = 2, etc.
```

Comment: yes but your code not working. my full sql code are     SELECT course.course_name,course_enroll_student.std_id FROM `course` LEFT JOIN course_enroll_student ON course_enroll_student.course_id=course.id                                                                         change the code and get output

Comment: Update your question with the actual data, formatted as tables.  Then, I can update my answer, if that be warranted.

Comment: thank you for your comment but I am not able to update my question for insufficient point

Comment: Then add a link to a screen capture containing the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `NOT IN`

```
$std_id =1;

SELECT *
FROM course
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT course_id 
                  FROM course_to_student 
                  WHERE std_id = $std_id )
```